# How to match a pattern and exclude another pattern within a string in Perl

Tags: perl, expression, matching

My objective is to match a pattern that doesn't contain '#' before the pattern, for example this:

```
array = ("# abc", "# abcd" "abc" " abc ", "abcd" "abc # foo")
```

I want to match "abc". " abc" . "abcd" . "abc # foo"
What regular expression do I need so as to match only patterns of 'abc' that do not contain '#'?

I tried `m/[^#]+abc/g` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want `#` anywhere before `abc`, you were almost there. Try this: `^[^#]*abc`.

Answer (score 2):

look for regex lookbehind and lookahead.

something like this:

```
m/^(?<!#).*/g
```

may work, it's a negative look behind.

Answer (score 2):

Your criterion isn't at all clear. Do you want to reject anything that has `#` as the first character?

```
print "$_\n" for grep /^[^#]/, @array;
```

will do that. But if you also want to check for the `abc` after possible leading space then you need

print "$_\n" for grep /^\s*abc/, @array;

these produce the same results from your data and select the items you say you want.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, it uses negative lookahead:

```
^[^#]*abc(?!(.*#))
```

New thoughts...

I read carefully your question again and I found out I didn't get exactly what you meant. Your intention is really confused and all I can say for sure is you DON'T want to get a match if the string has 1 or many # behind abc in the same line (and I guess you don't care if there's something else or not between them). I was confused because you explicitly say you WANT to match "abc # foo" but at the same time incoherently you say "to match only patterns of 'abc' that do not contain '#'".

If we want to follow this new interpretation, the correct regular expression may be:

```
(?<!(#.*))abc.*
```

The expression will not consume any text behind abc and will match from that point on if only anything before doesn't contain a # at all.

Comment: My objective is to match a pattern that doesn't contain '#' before the pattern.

Comment: Yes I undestand...then what I replied in the first part of my answer was ok. Both my solutions involve negative look-around so they DON'T consume text not regarding the pattern you want to include -in the 1st  case abc and in the 2nd case abc.*